# Python tKinter adds apostrophe to list

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I'm working on an Python script with a GUI.
I can read out some colors using get().

The problem is that when I want to use these colors to draw shapes using PIL, Python adds apostrophes to the beginning and end of the list.

```
def add_color_lines():
    the_color=tab_lines_colors_input.get()
    lines_color_list.append(the_color)
    print(lines_color_list)
```

This is the output:

> '"white","black","grey"'

I want it to be:

> "white","black","grey"

What am I doing wrong?
Why does the script add apostrophes to the list?

This is what I add:

[image: This is what I add]

This is what I get. Notice the apostrophes next to the brackets.
[image: This is what I get. Notice the apostrophes after the brackets.]

PIL cannot work with this because it says:

> ValueError: unknown color specifier: '"white","black","grey"'

Comment: Try `lines_color_list.extend(the_color.replace('"', "").split(","))`

Comment: It is hard to tell what is wrong without a [mre].

Comment: You haven't given us enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide output of 

`print(the_color)`

and

 `print(type(lines_color_list))`. 

Ideally, in python when a list is printed it should show ["white","black","grey"]

Comment: Added some screenshots and error message.

Comment: You need to input something like `white,black,grey` instead of `"white","black","grey"`.  Then split the string by comma and add the colors into the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string it's giving with the `split()` function.

```
output = lines_color_list.split(",")
```

This should output this list

```
['"white"', '"black"', '"gray"']
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, as mentioned by @acw1668 when you get the input form the text, it should just be color without quotes. `white,black,grey`

Now, in change the code to use `the_color.split(",")` and append that values to the list using `lines_color_list += the_color.split(",")`

```
lines_color_list = []
def add_color_lines():
    global lines_color_list
    the_color=tab_lines_colors_input.get()
    lines_color_list += the_color.split(",")
    print(lines_color_list)
```

The reason of apostrophe/single quote (') is how print function prints string elements of a list. Try this out to see how it prints.

Sample 1:
# Three elements in a list
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(my_list)

output

```
 ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Sample 2:

```
 # Three element in a list
 my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
 print(my_list)
```

output

```
 ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Sample 3:

```
 # One element in a list
 my_list = ["a, b, c"]
 print(my_list)
```

output

```
 ['a, b, c']
```

Sample 4 (your current scenario):

```
my_list = []
my_text = '"a", "b", "c"'
my_list.append(my_text) # Single element in the list
print(my_list)
```

output

```
 ['"a, b, c"']
```

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lines_color_list' referenced before assignment` caught at the line `lines_color_list += the_color.split(",")` inside `add_color_lines()`.  Either add `global lines_color_list` or use `lines_color_list.extend(the_color.split(","))`.